# LEFT JOIN - with kept empty main record

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two related tables `Cars` and `AddItems` and the relation 1 to 0 or many between them, so there are Cars with or without additional items.

I need the query which will always result with Cars as single records and additional records for additional car items like:

```
CarName | ItemName
========+=========
Car1    |          <- car without additional items
Car2    |          <- car with additional items but this solo record needed as well
Car2    | Item1
Car2    | Item2
Car3    |
Car3    | Item3
```

If I use simple LEFT OUTER JOIN I cannot get this solo record of car when car has joined additional items.

I could get something like:

```
SELECT carname,NULL AS itemname FROM cars

UNION

SELECT c.carname,ai.itemname
FROM cars c
LEFT JOIN additems ai ON ai.id_car=c.id
```

Is there any simpler/better (joinning) way without UNION?

Comment: What is your final output? Also please post the sample data from additems table?

Comment: You can replace the `UNION` by `UNION ALL` iff you replace the `LEFT JOIN` by a `JOIN`.

Comment: UNION is the way to go here. You need the record from cars (with no relationship to additem) AND a record per car/item combination (inner join relationship). Only way to combine those 2 is a UNION.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UNION ALL` doesn't do deduplication (which is needed because the cars query and the `LEFT JOIN` both yield the *bare* cars)

`UNION` is only costly because it removes the duplicates, often causing a sort. Not creating duplicates in the first place is cheaper.

---

```
   -- all the casrs
SELECT carname,NULL AS itemname
FROM cars

UNION ALL

   -- additional detail records, if any
SELECT c.carname,ai.itemname
FROM cars c
JOIN additems ai ON ai.id_car=c.id
ORDER BY 1,2 NULLS FIRST
        ;
```

Comment: Ok I agree, although both combination will result with the same resultset, the combination of UNION ALL and JOIN (instead of UNION and LEFT JOIN) is better solution because id does not include process of checking and removing duplicate records.

Answer (score 1):

Your version is OK. Alternatively you can use LATERAL

```
SELECT t.*
FROM cars c
CROSS JOIN  LATERAL (
      SELECT c.carname, null FROM DUAL
      UNION ALL
      SELECT c.carname, i.itemname 
      FROM additems i 
      WHERE i.carname = c.carname
    ) t
ORDER BY 1, 2 NULLS FIRST;
```